# How can we convert PDF of URL to Convert.ToBase64String in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have one URL which will ask Open/Save PDF when we browse it. I need to convert this pdf to Convert.ToBase64String in Javascript. I have one simple URL which have the PDF.

The URL is like

[This](https://xyz.crm4.dynamics.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=icofz2ffbc0my0vmpnmr2ybq&Culture=3081&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=a7e4ca6bf55a4caebd98f1c8e29f3c03&OpType=Export&FileName=Quote.rdl&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF)

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define `div` to create the link inside it

   `<div id="getpdf">
      <i>Generating PDF file, please wait..</i>
   </div>`
2. Then convert your PDF file containted in `PDFAsString` variable and create the inline datauri link like this to show this PDF inline:

   ```
   // create base 64 encoded string
   var PDFContentBase64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(PDFAsString))));

   var pdfdiv = document.getElementById("getpdf");`

   pdfdiv.innerHTML = "<h3><a title=\"View PDF file\" href=\"data:application/pdf;base64,' + PDFContentBase64 + '\">Click here to VIEW PDF<\/a></h3>";`
   ```

UPDATE: (thanks to @roland) If you need to support IE8 and older browsers then consider N. Zackas's [implementation](https://github.com/nzakas/computer-science-in-javascript/tree/master/encodings/base64) of base64 encoding.

Comment: Old browsers (IE8) don't provide a default implementation. See N. Zackas implementation as shim/polyfill: https://github.com/nzakas/computer-science-in-javascript/tree/master/encodings/base64

Comment: @Eugene M: What is PDFAsString? Is this a URL of PDF?

Comment: @KartikPatel PDFAsString should represent the content of the PDF file as is (for example, here is the min pdf file http://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0004.html )